# Making a counter in a recursive function using pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, count

I would like to count how many moves there are made in the function move. If it is possible i would like to use pointers for it so i can learn more about that.

I've made a counter using a global but now i would like to use pointers but everything i tried failed.

```
void move(unsigned int moves, char source, char spare, char dest)
{
    if (moves == 0) {
    /* no move: nothing to do */
    }
    else {
        move(moves - 1, source, dest, spare);
        printf("Move disk %d from pole %c to pole %c.\n", moves, source, 
dest);
        move(moves - 1, spare, source, dest);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char source = 'A';
    char spare = 'B';
    char dest = 'C';

    int moves = size();

    move(moves, source, spare, dest);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do post some of the things you tried, so we can help you understand why they didn't work :)

Comment: No need to keep it global variable. Just give it a value in main() itself, or where ever you want to call move() from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to alter a variable given in the parameter list. You can do so by using pointers. For example:

```
void move(int *pa)
{
    (*pa)++;  // increase the counter by one

    if (*pa < 5) move(pa);
}

void main(void)
{
    int a = 0;

    move(&a);
}
```

Comment: Everytime i try this i get the error "Too few arguments to function move" I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Nobody can know what you are doing wrong, unless you show your code

Comment: I found my fault and used this method to get to my goal. Thanks for the help!